# How to create an unqualified catch block in dynamics AX?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009

How to create an unqualified catch block in Dynamics AX ?

This is said dev help for AX2009sp1, but there is no example of it.  All valid catch blocks need the exception type as mandatory parameter, for instance:

```
catch(exception::error) 
{ 
   : 
}
```

have I missed something?
br,

Answer (score 1):

You should leave the catch clause without parameter.

```
try
{
   //...      
}
catch
{
   //... 
}
```

Here is an excelent screencast on exception handling:

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/mfp/Exception-handling-in-X/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know AX, but I can offer some suggestions; you could try omitting the exception parameter all together (i.e. `catch() {...}`, or using the most generally type possible for the exception parameter (i.e. `object` or the equivalent in your language).  That's at least how it works in many other languages.

Answer (score 0):

"One strategy is to have the last catch statement leave the exception type unspecified"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893385.aspx